# AgGrid Customized (Selected) Row Styling

Tags: css, reactjs, row, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to add customized styling to every second row in my AgGrid.
I am using the following snippet of code in my `onGridReady`:

```
gridOptions.getRowStyle = function (params) {
  if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
    return { background: "#f0f1f4" };
};
```

The issue I am having is I would like to add a variation indicating whether the row is selected or not. Currently the style remains the same either way.
What should I add to my code to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for reading and responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AgGrid exposes multiple class names of each row elements to describe its current state (`ag-row`, `ag-row-odd`, `ag-row-selected`...). You can take advantage of that information to override the row style if it's currently selected like below:

```css
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-row.ag-row-odd {
  background-color: pink;
}
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-row.ag-row-odd.ag-row-selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

### [Live Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/HGA3QfJYcmSInYUu?preview)

Comment: Thank you NearHuscarl
Will try this in my application.